# Multiple currencies in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, currency, number-to-currency

I want to be able to support multiple (3 for now) currencies on my website. I am a beginner and have doubts on how to do this . I have searched a bit and I have a list of questions. Following are my requirements.

- I do not want to change the labels/text on my website, but just the
  price of the products based on selected currency .I have found 2 ways
  to do it .

  - Using the money gem https://github.com/RubyMoney/money
  - Using I18n https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n

Please suggest which one is better to go for (for an ecommerce website). Also , are there any good tutorials on how to implement them.

- I want to be able to detect the user's IP and set the currency based on his country. I also want to give the user the option to change his currency using a dropdown. I found a gem using which we can do this "github.com/priithaamer/geoip-rails" . 
  Is this the correct way to do it or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I would use the money gem for everything with money and the geocoder gem for the IP -> Geo Lookup.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder

The money gem is very self explaining.